# Catch input field for "type in answer" type on iOS Anki app

Tags: anki

There is a bug in iOS Anki app. When I type thai in this field tone marks are being cut on top of it: 
[image: Anki iOS input field]

I think I can fix it by increasing padding or something like that using CSS but I don't know how to catch this field in the template. Is there any HTML class or id to match from CSS?

Thanks.

P.S. I tried this:
`input { ... }`

and this:
`[contenteditable] { ... }`

and even this:
`[placeholder="type in the answer"] { ... }`

But nothing works. I am starting to thing that it is not even an HTML being used there. Maybe some native for iOS input or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey for those who landed here... It is native iOS widget and we have no control over it. Though tone glyph trimming was resolved:
https://anki.tenderapp.com/discussions/ankimobile/9706-catch-input-field-for-type-in-answer-type-on-ios